# \usepackage{titlesec} Font formatting question

Tags: titlesec

I'm trying to format the chapter title so that it is **not** in all caps. I'm using titlesec. Is there something about the following code that is causing it to go all caps? Thanks.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\scshape}{\chaptertitlename}{0pt}{\vskip 0pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. `\scshape` is small caps so probably that’s what needs to go. But instead of posting a code fragment it’s more helpful to include the fragment in a small complete document that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: That was the issue. A quick fix by replacing \scshape with \normalfont  Thank you!